# Reduction between problems where problem A solves problem B with probability $\frac{2}{3}$

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

Suppose we have a problem, $A$, and a machine $T_A$ that solves $A$.

Now, let's say we have a problem $B$ that is solvable with a polynomial number of calls to $T_A$, and we call $T_B$ the machine that solves $B$ by calling $T_A$. But $T_B$ solves $B$ with probability $\frac{2}{3}$.

Does $B$ still reduce to $A$ in this case? $B$ is solvable, with probability $\frac{2}{3}$, using $A$, but it isn't solvable with certainty.

Comment: Depending on the definition of "reduce", and on which complexity classes you operate on (e.g P, NP, BP)

Comment: $T_A$ solves $A$ but $T_B$ does not solve $B$ (at least not in the same sense).

Comment: @YvesDaoust But if were considering a complexity class like "BPP" or some other probabilistic one, it would "solve" B? (as nir shahar implied)

Comment: @LoicStoic: obviously. As $T_A$ will always solve $A$, in this context $B$ reduces to $A$.